# R - Connect to MySQL using VPN in R

Tags: mysql, r, vpn

I want to run an R script on a remote server that depends on a MySQL connection that requires VPN. I do this on my local machine using a Cisco VPN client.

Is there any way to facilitate a MySQL connection for an R application where VPN is required?

More specifically, I'm interested in facilitating either a knitr script to produce html on the remote server or to deploy my shiny app on the remote server, but for both I would need the MySQL queries to run against a server via VPN. Any thoughts on this process or work-arounds would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: RMySQL isn't aware of the VPN. If it can see the host, it'll connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time has passed since asked but I found a solution to this or a similar problem. To connect to my database I need to do it via a VPN that I don't need to be connected 24/7.

```
cmd <- unname(Sys.which("rasdial"))
cmd_args <- c('"VPN NAME"', userID, pass)
system2(command = cmd, args= cmd_args)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), ... )
# Do your stuff

# Close the connection
cmd_args <- c('"VPN NAME"', '/DISCONNECT')
system2(command = cmd, args= cmd_args)
```

In this way I can automate the script in the task scheduler

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use PuTTY to connect to the vpn. This is through MS Windows 7/8 ***Once connected via PuTTY something like this to connect to MySQL:

```
YourvpnDB <- dbConnect(
MySQL() 
, user="enter your database user name here" 
, password=" enter your database password here " 
, db=" enter the name of your database here " 
, host="127.0.0.1" )
```

I have not tried but should work in theory :)